# Setting xml to body

Tags: xml, apache-camel

is it possible to set body as xml? for example

```
<setBody>
   <xml>
      <root>
         <subRoot> </subRoot>
      </root>
   </xml>
</setBody>
```

I don't want to get it as string but as org.w3c.dom.Document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a `<constant>` tag surrounding your XML, and you may need to enclose your XML body in a `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` tag - it may not care if it is within a constant.

If this returns a string, then just convert it to a document with `<convertBodyTo type="org.w3c.dom.Document" />` following the `setBody` tags.